# Add theme to new store in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-theme

I have 2 shop and 2 same themes for both the Stores

1: abc.com with theme Custom/Theme1

2: xyz.com with theme Custom/Theme2

abc.com load fine, but xyz.com does not load template and layout, t config in the backend like this but it not work. Please help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the folder structure as well as the settings for Theme1 website?

Comment: hi  Enzo Perrotta, please check update question

Comment: Firstly can i recommend you remove the numerical values as i have had similar issues with themes and naming conventions possibly name your theme primary and secondary. did you check your cache. what happens when assign the new theme? and are you setting it on the right view

Comment: hi  Dava Gordon, because this is a example, i change name it like this. if i change default of new theme to theme1 in backend, it work. but if it is theme2, it not work

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" you mean that you see the base template or missing assets? Can you also check there is no design change set in `Admin / System / Design` ?

Comment: yes Enzo Perrotta

Comment: did you add it to Admin / System / Design in the first place

Comment: hi  Dava Gordon, i added it in first